# MongoDb Duplicate Keys with versionned document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a problem of `E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxxxx index: _id_ dup key:` since I decide to add version with the @Version annotation to an object.

```
@Version
private long version;
```

When the obj is modified, I use `mongoTemplate.save(obj);` to override the document and the error pop a that time.

All works fine before the versionned doc.

Do you have an idea ? Because I don't have.

The objs are stored with mongoDb 3.6

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you add version to your document you have to change it.
version and id create a tuple key

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to save a new copy of the object. Without versioning there was no problem.

I solved the problem by saving directly the obj.